# Implementing 301 redirects with Hook BeforePageRedirect

Tags: redirect, mediawiki

For SEO purposes I'd like to introduce 301 redirects instead of the normal redirects in my wiki. I have found a few pages which described how to do so by manually editing the mediawiki files - however to maintain an updatable environment I'd prefer other approaches.

I did find a hook which I believe could make this possible, however I am unsure on how to use [Manual:Hooks/BeforePageRedirect](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/BeforePageRedirect)

Comment: What makes you think that SEO requires 301 redirects? A 301 redirect adds another HTTP request, which will make your total load time higher and hence your page less appreciated by (some) search engines. What really matters is that the redirects contain a canonical URL. They do by default in MediaWiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this extension with 302 changed to 301: http://svn.wikimedia.org/svnroot/mediawiki/trunk/extensions/HTTPRedirect/HTTPRedirect.php?